# Magento Reindex Isn't Automatic

Tags: reindex

When I change a product in terms of its category Magento doesn't reindex automatically - I have to do it manually. Is this how it's meant to work? Its very annoying. We have set up a cronjob to run every night but i've just had the following back from the client:

1. The scheduled daily re-index does not do the full indexing list, essentially missing out the search indexing. (I do this manually when I do any additions/ movements

Thanks

Comment: What is the version of magento you are working on ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your indexer configuration in the System > Configuration tab.

For low volume sites you could set them all to run on save, which would ensure everything relevant is indexed at the time the changes are made.

This approach will be problematic if you have many people editing products at once, but will probably suit your scenario best.